Android Studio crashes when opening layout xml file
I can open and run apps in AS, however I cannot edit xml files in the layout folder. Every time I open it, the layout editor pops up for 2 seconds and then the android studio crashes with the error in log:

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fde3865b671, pid=4139, tid=5716
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (21.0.3) (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
Problematic frame:
C  [libfreetype.so.6+0x84671]
Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with   "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to   /home/myusername/core.4139)

I suppose the libfreetype.so is the problem. I am running Android Studio Ladybug on Ubuntu 20. I can manually edit xmls outside the AS enviroment, when I open them in standalone texteditor. This works, but it is inconvenient. Could anyone guide me how to fix this issue?
I tried to look into problem found here. But this is a different file and for different version of AS. I don't want any workaround as found here
Edit: I updated ubuntu version from 18 to 20 so I meet the minimum requirements on glibc version 2.31

So apparently it might be a glib related issue after all. Minimum requirements for AS say that at least version 2.31 is needed for Ladybug. However, it works just after upgrading ubuntu to 22 and glib with it to version 2.35. After upgrade, I can edit layouts finally.
